# Difference between scale_color_grey and scale_colour_grey in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

What is the Difference between 
`scale_color_grey` and 
`scale_colour_grey` in ggplot2?

`Color` and `Colour` appear several times in `ggplot2`. Is there a general rule for the difference between color and colour in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference concerning the code. British English vs. American English.

```
library(ggplot2)
identical(scale_colour_grey, scale_color_grey)
#[1] TRUE
```

Both are calling the same function:

```
> scale_color_grey
function (..., start = 0.2, end = 0.8, na.value = "red") 
{
    discrete_scale("colour", "grey", grey_pal(start, end), na.value = na.value, 
        ...)
}
```